# 'Have been persuading' v. 'have been trying to persuade'

Tags: word-meaning

Should I say, for example,

> I've been **persuading** her to apply for half an hour.

or

> I've been **trying to persuade** her to apply for half an hour.

? Does the verb 'persuade' (or 'convince', for that matter) necessarily imply the success of the efforts? Or fruitless attempts also count as persuasion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are mostly correct.**

If you have been persuading her for half an hour, it may mean that your efforts have been successful, or it may mean that she is still undecided but is heavily leaning towards taking your advice.

The second sentence is probably more common, as it implies that, as you guessed, your attempts have not been successful. It doesn't necessarily mean that you've given up, it just means that she has not yet accepted your advice.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You’ve captured the question correctly. The verb *persuade* Is inherently what linguists call perfective—a persuading is an event that results from perhaps protracted efforts, thus for instance,

> After much debate she became persuaded.

So your second example fits standard usage.